# If POD has unique IP address, what will be the IP address of each container in POD?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Suppose I have 2 containers in POD.
Will each POD have a unique IP address ? 
If so what will be the IP addresses of each container  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All containers in pod share the same IP address and localhost. You must define different port number for each container.

Comment: Does it mean that each container in POD is a separate process in POD ?

Comment: sure, each container in pod is a separate process in a separate cgroup. However all containers in pod share network namespace so they share same IP address and localhost and iptables rules.

Comment: It means port numbers are also shared across all containers. rit ?

Comment: containers within pod can talk to each other using localhost, because every container listens on localhost common to all containers in pod. Also using localhost bypasses network stack so it is generally faster.

Answer (score 3):

The networking namespace (IP) of pod is managed by **infra container** which just does nothing more than being a placeholder. All of the other Containers in pod are sharing this IP Address  (Pod IP) rather than using host network namespace or host IP.

It is controlled by the following parameter of [**kubelet**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/#options)

`--pod-infra-container-image` : The image whose network/ipc namespaces containers in each pod will use. (default "k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1")

following article describe it in more detail.

> In Kubernetes, the pause container serves as the "parent container" for all of the containers in your pod. The pause container has two core responsibilities. First, it serves as the basis of Linux namespace sharing in the pod. And second, with PID (process ID) namespace sharing enabled, it serves as PID 1 for each pod and reaps zombie processes.
>   [almighty-pause-container](https://www.ianlewis.org/en/almighty-pause-container)